# How can I configure TM4J for use another language when I'm writing test-cases using gherkin notation?

Tags: testing, automation, jira, bdd, jira-plugin

The Test Management for Jira plugin has the ability to describe test scenarios using Gherkin notation (BDD). Gherkin notation supports  another languages, however, it is impossible to save test cases. (test case will save only when using English). How can you configure TM4J to use another language when writing BDD test cases?

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue with the provider and they responded telling me that this is not possible yet.

They suggested me to make an improvement request in their [Ideas Portal](https://zephyr-scale-server-dc.ideas.aha.io/ideas/).

There was already such a suggestion there ([TM4JS-I-156](https://zephyr-scale-server-dc.ideas.aha.io/ideas/TM4JS-I-156)). I voted on it and suggest everyone interested to do the same. ;)